# Ajax.BeginForm does not raise "submit" event in IE 7 / 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC 3, I've declared an ajax form like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveRegistrationConfirmationRequest", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "verify-email-result", HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { id = "request-form" }))
```

and I'm using jQuery to bind to the "submit" event (the `alert` is just for testing):

```
$("#request-form").submit(function () {
    alert("submit");
    if (!$("#agree-checkbox").is(":checked")) {
        $("#agree-dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    }
});
```

In Chrome and Firefox on Windows, the event handler is called and I see the alert.  In IE 7 and 8, I don't see the alert and the form is submitted.

If I change the code to use a non-ajax form, then the handler is called in IE:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRegistrationConfirmationRequest", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "request-form" }))
```

What do I need to do to get this working with an ajax form in IE?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) event:

```
$("#request-form").ajaxSend(function (evt, request, settings) {
    if (!$("#agree-checkbox").is(":checked")) {
        request.abort();
        $("#agree-validation").addClass("field-validation-error");
        $("#agree-validation").removeClass("field-validation-valid");

    }
});
```

This works in IE 7 and 8, Firefox, and Chrome.